# Why do I need to do list.add(new ArrayList<>(temp)); when adding a list to a 2D list?

Tags: java

I was working on a permutation problem and I have the code below:

```
public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
    List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    helper(list,new ArrayList<Integer>(), nums);
    return list;
}

private void helper(List<List<Integer>> list, List<Integer> temp, int[] num) {
    if (temp.size() == num.length) {
        list.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            if (temp.contains(num[i])) continue;
            temp.add(num[i]);
            helper(list, temp, num);
            temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is why do I need to write:

```
list.add(new ArrayList<>(temp));
```

instead of :

```
list.add(temp);
```

Comment: What does `new ArrayList<>(temp)` do?

Comment: What happens if you don't?

Comment: If I do list.add(temp); I get empty lists in my answer.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis It creates a new ArrayList with the value temp.

Comment: @user2817869 Of course you do, you remove all the elements from `temp`. If you don't use `new ArrayList<>(temp)` (or some other kind of copy), then you only have **one** `ArrayList`.

Comment: You are probably modifying temp else where.

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi **Elsewhere?** It's at `temp.remove(temp.size() - 1);`

Comment: You need to add a _copy_ of `temp` or else any _future_ modifications you make to `temp` will apply to the list in `list`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch No probably outside of this method. Since the .remove is in the else statement..

Comment: @JawadLeWywadi Look again, `helper` is recursive.

Comment: Your are right I missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new ArrayList<>(temp)` creates a new `ArrayList` whose elements are the same as `temp`. This means that if the invoker of `helper` does something like:

```
ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
// populate temp here
object.helper(list, temp, someIntArray);
temp.clear()
```

the list stored by `helper` is not affected by `clear`.